# How do I filter inbound/outbound traffic based on words?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, traffic-filtering

I need to filter some outbound requests to certain sites based on the request headers and post data. I might be interested in filtering inbound packets as well.

They are in plain text (ie not https).

How can I do this, in the easiest way possible?

I am using Window 10.

Comment: why do you want to do this, whats the use case?

Comment: A game leaks information and the game developer doesn't care. Blocking one particular post request prevents that. I can't filter all traffic or the game doesn't work, so I need to filter with a specific keyword.